# It is posible to get output of external barcode scanner to Django

Tags: django, barcode, pyusb

In my project I have `external bar-code scanner`, I want get `bar-code scanner output on my django project,` is this possible? if any have article or blog please share

Comment: How scanner output data? What the structure of the data? What do you want to get from it? Please provide more information about it.

Comment: @Gasanov i think scanned data gives string format, i wand to display barcode number in web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barcode scanners are meant to be indistinguishable from a keyboard. While you can send codes to the scanner to get it to behave differently, no extra programming is necessary.

If you are wanting the external scanner to perform tasks that keyboards can't perform, then you will have to examine the documentation for the scanner and find out what setup codes to send it. Most scanners are compatible within a brand, but the codes will vary between brands.

You should think of programming for a scanner the same way you program for any character input device.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is very specific I would love to give also a specific answer.

**Yes it's possible.**

Comment: `if any have article or blog please share?` read question carefully